# Merge a large Dask dataframe with a small Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask

Following the example here: [YouTube: Dask-Pandas Dataframe Join](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrc3cpf3PKU) I attempting to merge a ~70GB Dask data frame with a ~24MB that I loaded as a Pandas dataframe.

The merge is on two columns A and B, and I did not set any as indices:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar

small_df = pd.read_csv(dataframe1) # as pandas
large_df = dd.read_csv(dataframe2) #as dask.dataframe

df2 = large_df.merge(small_df, how='left', left_on=leftcolumns, right_on=rightcolumns) #do the merge

A = df2[df2['some column'] == 'somevalue'] #do a reduction that would fit on my computer

pbar = ProgressBar()
pbar.register()

result = A.compute()
```

I'm using a Windows computer with 16GB of RAM and 4 cores.
I use the progress bar to assess how far along the merging process it is. I left it all night last night. I restarted it this morning and so far its about half an hour in and 0% progress.

Thank you and I appreciate your help,

**Update**

I tried it on my Mac with 8GB of RAM and worked pretty well. I have the Dask distribution that comes with Anaconda I believe. I don't think I did anything different in any case.

I share my results and time following the above coding (21 minutes):

```
In [26]: C = result1.compute()
[########################################] | 100% Completed | 21min 13.4s
[########################################] | 100% Completed | 21min 13.5s
[########################################] | 100% Completed | 21min 13.6s
[########################################] | 100% Completed | 21min 13.6s
```

**Update 2**

I updated to the latest version of Dask on my Windows computer and it worked well.

Comment: Just a sidenote, is using `df` instead of `df2` in the boolean indexing a mistake? `A = df2[df['some column'] == 'somevalue']`

Comment: Oh sorry, I just saw what you meant. Yes, that is a mistake. I fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @dleal, since this question is resolved, could you provide the solution as an answer and accept it (encouraged even if it's your own question), to remove this from unanswered list?  Thanks!

Comment: To add to @Garrett 's comment: please be specific about the Dask version you had and what did you just update to.

Comment: You could have also used joblib, and run the process on many cores.

Genera idea is to split the large dataset into an array of smaller ones (i.e. `[large_df_part1, ... , large_df_partN]` and then use joblib to allocate to them to different processors.

Comment: Use BigQuery to handle this, Its resources and easy way to query by SQL, make it very easy.

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate over unique equal values and assign other columns with loop:

```
unioun_set = list(set(small_df['common_column']) & set(large_df['common_column']))
for el in union_set:
    for column in small_df.columns:
        if column not in large_df.columns:
            large_df.loc[large_df['common_column'] == el,column] = small_df.loc[small_df['common_column'] ==  el,column]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can join a large Dask DataFrame to a smaller pandas DataFrame with Dask.

The code below creates a Dask DataFrame with multiple partitions and execute a left join with a small pandas DataFrame:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

# create sample 'large' pandas dataframe
df_large = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": ["Azza", "Brandon", "Cedric", "Devonte", "Eli", "Fabio"], 
        "Age": [29, 30, 21, 57, 32, 19]
    }
)

# create multi-partition dask dataframe from pandas
large = dd.from_pandas(df_large, npartitions=2)

# create sample small pandas dataframe
small = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": ["Azza", "Cedric", "Fabio"], 
        "City": ["Beirut", "Dublin", "Rosario"]
    }
)

# merge dask dataframe to pandas dataframe
join = ddf.merge(df2, how="left", on=["Name"])

# inspect results
join.compute()
```

I've written a blog post about merging Dask DataFrames [here](https://coiled.io/blog/dask-dataframe-merge-join/) that may be a helpful resource for you. Especially the notes on setting index and sorted vs unsorted joins may be helpful to speed up your computations.

Answer (score -2):

While working with big data, partitioning data is very important at the same time having enough cluster and memory size is mandatory.

You can try using `spark`.

DASK is a pure Python framework, which does more of same i.e. it allows one to run the same Pandas or NumPy code either locally or on a cluster. Whereas, Apache Spark brings about a learning curve involving a new API and execution model although with a Python wrapper.

You can try partitioning data and storing it into `parquet` files.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question in a meaningful way.